# this.parent.parent.removeChild(this.parent) not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, removechild

I am facing an issue because of removeChild method in javascript.

I am using below code to remove a div tag.

**this.parent.parent.removeChild(this.parent).**

that code is working pretty fine in FF but it give me error in IE7/8.

**" Error: Object doesn't support this property or method ".**

is removeChild method is not supported in IE7/8 or is there any other alternate of this method?

Regards,
Mahendra Athneria
Mumbai,Maharashtra,India

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your precious time and reply. special thanks to **Meder**.

Finally i found the solution.

Here is my solution and analysis.

actually in my code i was using **this.parent.parent.removeChild(this.parent)** to delete the child.
this.parent return **[object window]** and **[object window]** does not support the removeChild property. to use removeChild method we need the **Element** and to get the element i made some change in my code.

**1st - change the method signature.**
function removeCriteria(thisObj) {.....}

**2nd -only for IE**
thisObj.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(thisObj.srcElement.parentElement);
this solution works for me and hope my analysis is right :-)

For @Meder & other seniors - correct me if i am wrong.

Regards,
Mahendra
Mumbai,Maharashtra,India

Answer (score 1):

It should be `parentNode` not `parent`

Comment: Hi Meder,  yes it is parent only. please check my code which i have added in my question. but i am facing the issue with parent too.

Comment: Please post a full demo to jsfiddle.net

Comment: Put HTML in the HTML box. CSS in CSS, and so forth. Use absolute urls for media.

Comment: it is not working there. i had put html,css and js code on the proper place and run it. but when i clicked on the button it give me error that function is not defined.